# i2c not detecting on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5

Tags: pi-4, i2c

Just purchased a new board - Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5 - rev b03115.

Trying to use i2c to interface with

1. Adafruit PiOLED - 128x32 Monochrome OLED Add-on for Raspberry Pi
2. Adafruit SCD-40 - True CO2, Temperature and Humidity Sensor - STEMMA QT / Qwiic (via SparkFun Qwiic or Stemma QT SHIM for Raspberry Pi / SBC)

Stacking the hat and shim results in neither device being seen when using `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`.

If I use just the OLED hat, it works.  However just the SHIM + sensor does not work.

I've deduced that the rev code for my board, `b03115`.  Anyone know if this is the cause of the i2c devices not being seen, or have other suggestions to try?

Have re-imaged the board several times.  The full setup works fine when swapping out the Pi 4 for a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2.  Thanks in advance!

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 1
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 2
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 3
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : BCM2711
Revision    : b03115
Serial      : 10000000########
Model       : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5
```

// Edit 1
Based on a suggestion from a forum member, I tried the same hardware configuration, but the Pi 3 micro SD.

The result that I was able to see the hat, but not the shim.

```
$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 3c -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

```
$ sudo i2cdetect -l
i2c-1   i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e804000)              I2C adapter
```

Comment: You say it works in the Pi3.  Does it work in the Pi4 if you use the Pi3 SD card?  Please edit the answer into your question.

Comment: Updated w/ the results of this suggestion ^.