# NameError: name 'I2C' is not defined (Raspberry Pi 4 Model B - Ubuntu 18.04 - adafruit_lidarlite)

Tags: i2c, python-3, ubuntu, raspberry-pi-os, adafruit

I am getting an issue while trying to use the library "adafruit_circuitpython_lidarlite".

Below are the details of my environment:

**1-** Distributor ID: [Ubuntu](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/)  (ubuntu-18.04.5-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi4.img.xz)

----> Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

----> Release: 18.04

----> Codename: bionic

**2-** Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4

**3-** [Germin Lidar Lite V3](https://www.garmin.com/en-US/p/557294)

**4-** SDA & SCL Ports

I am getting this issue on both versions (1.2.6 & 1.2.7).

Installed the lidarlite adafruite library with the below command:

```
sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-lidarlite
```

I enabled the **I2C** port from the `raspi-config` also, but I am still getting the same issue.

**I am not sure,** but [I read that this might be something with the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Revisions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135603/i2c-not-detecting-on-raspberry-pi-4-model-b-rev-1-5#:%7E:text=The%20full%20setup%20works%20fine%20when%20swapping%20out%20the%20Pi%204%20for%20a%20Raspberry%20Pi%203%20Model%20B%20Rev%201.2.%20Thanks%20in%20advance!).
I checked this on Revision 1.1 & Revision 1.4 of Raspberry 4 Model B.
But about 2 weeks ago the same worked on one of my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B without giving me any errors. But now that Pi is dead I don't know why. I changed the Pi and this problem started appearing.

I tried the same on the NVidia Jetson and the problem is the same there too.

[image: Error details]

[image: Information of my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B]

[image: I2C response]

Comment: What does `i2cdetect -y 1` report?

Comment: @joan I updated my question and added the response of the said command.

Comment: I assume the device at 0x3c is the sensor.  The Adafruit software is probably looking at bus 0 rather than bus 1.  You need to look at the code which defines/opens the I2C bus and make sure it uses bus 1.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the older installed version of the adafruit-blinka package.
I tried to update the package but I wasn't aware that I need to update my python first to installed the latest release of the package.

I installed the newer version of python (3.8.5) on my Raspberry Pi and installed the adafruit-blinka & adafruit-circuitpython-lidarlite again, and this fixed my issue.

Issue resolved after updating python and installing the newer version of blinka.